# Cannot install webpack with npm

Tags: npm, webpack, browserify, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to install **webpack** on windows-7-x64 with **npm**. It goes about 30% and then stops, usually at VM-browserify, but not always.

I've tried different variants, but none of them seems to work. Any thoughts on what can I do?

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.6.0 (x64) and npm.

D:\file>npm install -S webpack
loadDep:vm-browserify ->  | |###############----------------------------------|

D:\file>npm install webpack -S
loadDep:vm-browserify ->  / |###############----------------------------------|

D:\file>npm install -S webpack --cache-min 999999
loadDep:indexof -> addNam - |###############----------------------------------|

D:\file>npm install -S webpack --cache-min 999999
loadDep:indexof -> get    \ |###############----------------------------------|

D:\file>npm install -S webpack --cache-min 999999
loadDep:vm-browserify ->  \ |###############----------------------------------|

D:\file>npm install -g webpack
loadDep:vm-browserify ->  \ |###############----------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to delete node.js and reinstall the previous version 4.4.7 LTS